# $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] in all server environments

Tags: php

In a custom project of mine, a function is fully dependent on $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] variable. Does it always return the same value on all server environments? (IIS, Apache, etc.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supposed to.

I haven't done any empirical testing on it, but from the PHP [manual page for $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'REQUEST_URI'
>       The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance,
>   '/index.html'.

Comment: I guess only way to test this is to run a script on those servers which I do not have access to...

Comment: I think I have found a case where it is different between environments. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097060/php-apache-requesturi-different-behaviour