# PHP/Apache REQUEST_URI different behaviour?

Tags: wordpress, apache, url-rewriting, lamp

I am moving websites from one server to another. Both are on a similar variant of **Centos 5 x64** with **Apache 2.2** and **PHP 5.2.X**.

Some of my scripts ,including **Wordpress**, are behaving incorrectly. It turns out the issue is the difference between the `REQUEST_URI` global:

On the older server: `REQUEST_URI = /phpinfo.php`
On the new server: `REQUEST_URI = http://www.example.com/phpinfo.php`

I have changed my own code to accommodate either variant but don't really want to do it for **Wordpress** etc.

What do I need to do in `apache/php` to make `REQUEST_URI` behave as per the old server?

Comment: You would expect to see complete absolute URLs as the REQUEST_URI when a server is acting as an HTTP proxy. Could that be related?

Comment: Might want to try http://www.serverfault.com/ with this one, as it deals with changing the web server . . .

Comment: The server is not live yet so I have hooked up my browser to talk directly to the server as if it were a proxy. This allows me to check whether the apache virtual host configuration is working as expected before I repoint the DNS. Is this the cause?

Comment: Thanks pygorex1, I never knew that existed. Well be sure to use it for these types of question in the future.

Comment: If you get really stuck with this you could create a plugin for wordpress that normalises REQUEST_URI

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the old server is processing the request using the default vhost while the newer server uses a named virtual host (although that could be back to front).

Comment: They're actually both on vhosts. The problem was the HTTP proxy method I was using to test the site as bobince pointed out.